# Is there a checklist for setting up a new organization's website + CRM?

Tags: best-practice, civicrm-home

I'm meeting with an organization later this week to begin the process of seeing them up on civiCRM and a Drupal website.  Curious any of the people who does this regularly if you have a document that helps you cover all the information you need to obtain in order to get things started? Would you mind sharing it with me so that i can make sure this goes as smoothly as possible?

Answer (score 5):

Palante Tech has been building an internal document for this, but we haven't devoted much time to fleshing it out - it's more a "list of questions we wished we'd remembered to ask" and doesn't get into the important questions, like "What is this for?  Who will be using it?"  Nevertheless, here is our work-in-progress:

### All projects

- How much traffic does your site currently get, per Google Analytics/Piwik/etc.?
- Where is your site hosted?  Are you open/eager to moving your hosting?
- Who currently manages your website?
- Will there need to be multiple levels of permissions?  How granular/how many?

### CiviCRM projects

- How many contacts do you anticipate having on day 1?  How many contacts do you intend to add per month/year?
- What features of CiviCRM do you intend to use?  Donation management, mass e-mails, membership management, etc.?  Is a particular use driving the project?
- [If CiviMail] What sort of mail volume are you doing in your legacy system?
- What are your legacy data sources?  How many Excel/Google Docs/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed this section in the online User and Admin Guide:
http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/getting-prepared/identifying-your-needs/

Seems like a good start at least.

You also might check out this session video from CiviCon:
[Introduction & Transitioning to CiviCRM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVdN-B0WXnM)

Answer (score 1):

If we had such a thing we would certainly share it, but we do not. I think the needs of starting organizations vary from project to project, although there are certainly some standard tasks. But the devil is in the detail, and that tends to differ from project to project.